# ¿Disparador/Procedimiento/Cron con MySQL?

Tags: mysql, cron

¿Existe alguna forma de crear un disparador o un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL que se active, no por un evento (update, detele, insert) si no, por tiempo, es decir, que se active automáticamente por ejemplo, a las 24:00h?

Se que con Cron (nunca lo he utilizado por el momento) se puede programar tareas, pero creo que sólo del sistema operativo (en este caso Raspbian).

¿Se podría hacer con Cron?

Comment: Se me hace que estas buscando algo como un evento, que en MySQL son tareas que corren según un horario. Entonces puedes especificar el intervalo en el que quieres correr el evento, y ejecutar tu lógica. Esto crea un objeto en la BD. Aquí la documentación oficial: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html

Comment: Los usuarios normales también pueden programar tareas con cron.

Comment: @JhonRayo99 pon eso como respuesta (añadiendo un ejemplo y algo más de detalla). Parece que es lo que está buscando el usuario.

Comment: Gracias Jhon. He solucionado el problema... a medias. Resulta que, no se porque, pero como evento, con BEGIN y END y varias sentencias SQL, me da como error en el END y no funciona el Evento, peeeeeeeero, lo que si he podido hacer (de momento, mientras no consiga que func SOLO con el evento), es crear una función con las sentenc SQL (aquí NO da error con BEGIN y END) y hacer una llamada (una sóla sentencia no me da problemas) con un CALL al procedimiento. Es una chapuza, pero... funciona.

Comment: Hola, quería ver si lograste resolver este problema, yo necesito exactamente lo mismo que tu preguntaste, ejecutar una llamada a un procedimiento de la base de datos desde una tarea cron, no sé si tu pregunta iba exactamente a como hacerlo en un hosting, pero si es así es idéntico a lo que yo quiero, podrías orientarme? Gracias